# Get last element in a loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, texttemplate

```
for (int ixIdx = 0; ixIdx < tblAttributes.Count; ixIdx++)
      {
          bool Exclude = ExcludeColumn(tblAttributes[ixIdx].Name);
                  bool Primary = Primary(tblAttributes[ixIdx].Name);
                  if (Exclude || Primary)
          {
              continue;
          }
          else
          {
    #>    [<#= tblAttributes[ixIdx].MdlPart.InternalName #>]<#= ixIdx == tblAttributes.Count-1 ? "" : "," #>
    <#    }
        }
```

in the above code is in texttemplate file . what all i am trying to do is generate a comma for each element of list tblAttributes those comes in to else and stop comma at the last element of the list.....

The issue is as my condition is in else it is applying , but after that last elements are falling in to if block so it never stops the comma generation . so is there any possibility to find the last element that comes to else block....to get this done ...

or is there any work around for the whole process plz ....thanks........

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding what your issue is, but why not use `String.join`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk0xe5h0.aspx

Comment: problem is not generating comma , stopping by the last element with out disturbing my if  else conditions....the problem that arises there is last 3 r 4 elements fall in to if block so till before that elements goes to else and generates comma as they are not last element in the list....

Answer (score 3):

for your comma problem, you can do it like this for a general purpose:

```
string res = "";
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++)
    res += list[i] + ", ";
if (list.Count > 0) res += list[list.Count - 1];
```

in your particular case (since not every element is added to your string):

```
string res = "";
int i = 0;
while (i < tblAttributes.Count && (ExcludeColumn(tblAttributes[i].Name) || (Primary(tblAttributes[i].Name)))
    i++;

if (i < tblAttributes.Count) res += tblAttributes[i].Name;

for (; i < tblAttributes.Count; i++)
{
    if (!ExcludeColumn(tblAttributes[i].Name) && !(Primary(tblAttributes[i].Name))
        res += ", " + tblAttributes[i].Name;
}
```

that way you only add a comma if you have another element to add to your resulting string.
If there is no elements that match your condition the string will be empty.
If there is only one, your string won't have a comma at the end.
If there is more than one element, you place the comma before adding a new element, so no risks that your string ends with a comma either.

Comment: ya obviously it will work even my one will work...But i got issues of my if and else block... where it will fail..........problem is not generating comma , stopping by the last element with out disturbing my if else conditions....the problem that arises there is last 3 r 4 elements fall in to if block so till before that elements goes to else and generates comma as they are not last element in the list.

Comment: Ok now I think I fully understand your problem, I'll make an edit, it's more or less the same way to go

Comment: i am not gonna print in the if block just skipping that index.....and my i = tblAttributes.Count - 1 element is falling under if clause..so all the elements getting comma and last one as i am not printing just stays with last element falls else block printed with a comma as it is not the last element of list at that time.......what all will be helpful for me is to find the last element of the list that gonna enter else block....\

Comment: i won't that what i mentioned in the above comment\

Comment: you shouldn't have that problem with the code I posted in the edited answer if I understood you correctly, have you tried it? The code I posted will find the first element to be added, then for every other element to add it will add a coma before the element, so you won't have your if else block problem

Answer (score 0):

the simple thing u could do is

iterate the list in for loop and push the elements that satisfies ur conditions into a new list and then iterate the new list so that u can use the simple logic below to stop generating  the comma at the end of last element of the new list in the loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < newlist.Count; i++)
{ 
   <#= newlist[i] #><#= i == newlist.Count - 1 ? "" : "," #>
}
```

that will do thanks..........